black screen problem while running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I recently have installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my Dell laptop (specifications):

intel core i3 processor
amd-64 architecture
inbuilt graphics

Recently I have updated my laptop to Ubuntu 24.04 from 23.10. After installing, it works fine and runs smoothly, but after some time it blinks a black screen for about 5 seconds in the cycle of 10 minutes.
This problem was not in the beta version of Ubuntu 24.04. What is happening here?
There is no problem with my laptop because it works fine with other distros and I have tested it on about 20 different types of distros. Is there any problem with desktop environment?
Is someone has any explanation for it?

The upgrade path is not yet supported and may result in serious bugs https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/dont-upgrade-to-ubuntu-24-04-yet. Please try Ubuntu 24.04 from a live USB drive. If the issue is not there, then fresh install Ubuntu 24.04 and the problem should be gone.

I found some help here (I didn't actually read the title before trying things...)
For me I think it was related to my nvidia drivers. Some combination of update/upgrade/autoremove/purge nvidia drivers worked for me
I wasn't able to open TTY with CTRL + ALT + F3 (or others), but I was able to access a recovery version through grub Ubuntu Advanced -> <Latest version> (recovery) -> root -> [Enter] -> shell access. My setup always goes through grub because I dual boot. I'm not sure how to access it 'normally'
sudo apt update
# I'm not sure what the below line does, I was just following the linked instructions
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt upgrade -y
# There were a-lot of nvidia things removed here
sudo apt autoremove
# Remove nvidia stuff
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt upgrade -y
# More nvidia stuff was removed here
sudo apt autoremove

Now reboot
reboot


The issue is generated by the gdm3 display manager crash (error between choosing default video card)
My workaround for the reboot error "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." with the following scenario:

Enter system in TEXT mode run level 3
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target

Reboot your system
sudo reboot

After every reboot, enter in Ex. tty2 (Ctrl+Alt+F2), authenticate with you user and restart manually gdm3 (or your display manager)
sudo systemctl restrat gdm3



I solved this issue using this steps:

Update or Reconfigure Graphics Drivers
Sometimes the issue is related to GPU drivers and not the display manager. Ensure your drivers are up-to-date:

Install recommended drivers:
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Remove old caches:
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/gdm3
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache

Reboot:
sudo reboot


